# How to check os version in a iPhone/phonegap app and restrict the os version?

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

I want to check the os version of device before loading my phonegap/iOS app and want to support my app upto iOS 6 version. I want if app detects higher os version (lets take iOS7) then should throw some error or warning and terminates. How to do that?

Comment: You don't do that.  Forcing an app to quit is a violation of the App Store rules.

Comment: No I don't want to force quit the app. I just want to support my app upto certain os level and detect the device os version before loading. I am not worried about what it does, if it found any incompatible os version. I think you got my point?

Comment: setting Deployment target is better option for that you want load app related to iOS version.

Comment: You cannot do anything "before loading"

Answer (score 2):

get device version using this

```
NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
```